# get api keys of myspace and you tube

Tags: android, youtube-api, myspace

I want to integrate myspace and youtube in android.

So I tried below example example links.

For my space integration I have to define the api values of my space like this

```
    private static final String API_KEY = "";
    private static final String API_SECRET = "";
    private static final String API_CALLBACK_URL = "";
```

For getting this i tried in this [link](http://developer.myspace.com/Modules/Apps/Pages/CreateAppAccount.aspx)

So I got `API_KEY` and `API_SECRET_KEY` but I couldn't get `API_CALLBACK_URL` so please tell me how to get keys of my space.

Coming to youtube integration

In this also I want to get the api keys for integrate you tube in android.

```
     private static final String YOUTUBE_API_KEY = "";
     // Replace with your YTD App Engine hostname, e.g. ytd-test.appspot.com
     private static final String YTD_SERVER = "";
     private static final String YTD_MOBILE_SUBMISSION_URL = 
       "http://%s/mobile/PersistMobileSubmission";
     private static final String YTD_MOBILE_LOGIN_URL = 
      "http://%s/mobile/MobileAuthSub?protocol=androidytd";
```

for this values i used this [link](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html)

but I didn't get any key values. So please help me how to find the api key values of my space and you tube or send me the any working key values for testing.